# Regular Expressions for "C:\\"

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expressions that can find the string "C:\\".

My code is:

```
String test = "C:\\";  
String regex = "[a-z]*[A-Z]*[:]*\\";  
if(test.matches(regex))  
    System.out.println("Success!");  
else  
    System.out.println("Failure!");
```

I'm getting a PatternSyntaxException. I've tried with many regular expressions and the result is the same.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The simple (but probably useless) answer is `".*".

In this case, you apparently want something closer to: `"[a-zA-Z]:\\\\"`. This requires exactly one letter, then a colon, then a back-slash. Assuming your string is supposed to represent the root of some disk on Windows, it should be a lot closer than what you had in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence \\ has a special meaning in most languages.  Which is why its a bad choice as a path seperator.The problem you have here is that its has a special meaning in Java and in regular expressions. This means that \\\\ is turned into \\ in Java and \ in the regular expression.

BTW I think you need just "[a-zA-z]:\\\\"

OMG it has a special meaning on SO as well :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to double escape, once for Java string escape and once for regex escape:

```
String test = "C:\\";
String regex = "[a-zA-Z]:\\\\";
if ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find `C:\` explicitly, you could just use `String regex ="C:\\";` Not very flexible, but fits exactly.

What you are likely looking for is something like `String regex = "[A-Z]:\\\\";`
That says to "Match a single character in the range between "A" and "Z"" then "Match the character ":"" then "Match the character \".
If you need to include lowercase beginning letters use `String regex = "[a-zA-Z]:\\\\";` which matches a single character either between "a" and "z" or between "A" and "Z".

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `String.contains("C:\\")`?